# Reverse the data order

Tags: c++, linux, awk, reverse

Suppose, I have a file *(file.txt)* that contain few numbers with characters.

```
1 2 3 4 (23)

23 2 1 (51)

2 1 4 (11)
```

And, I would like to read it in reverse order as given below.

```
(23) 4 3 2 1

(51) 1 2 23

(11) 4 1 2
```

**I tried:**

```
awk '{print $NF,$0}' file.txt | sort -nr
```

Is there a command-line in **Linux** or a mini-code *(in AWK or in C++ or some other language)* to perform this task?

Comment: There are commands that *can* do this, like e.g. [`awk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html). Or you could make your own program to do this in C++ (why else would you tag this question C++?). If you have made your own program (in AWK or in C++ or some other language) and have problems with it, then you're more than welcome to show us what you tried, and explain what's wrong with it and we will try to help you. We will however ***not*** write your program for you.

Comment: I kept trying on the command line but keep failing. Here's the command I tried:
awk '{print $NF,$0}' file.txt | sort -nr

Comment: Nvm I finally  got it!
Thanks for letting me know abt the awk functionality!! effin powerfullll tool!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--){printf $i" "};printf "\n"}' file.txt
```

Output:

```
(23) 4 3 2 1 

(51) 1 2 23 

(11) 4 1 2
```

Comment: Never use `printf $i` wince it will fail cryptically and/or catastrophically when the input contains printf formatting characters such as `%s`. Always use `printf "%s", $i` instead. Also, `{printf $i" "};printf "\n"` will add a trailing blank char to the end of each line use `printf "%s%s", $i, (i>1?OFS:ORS)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your useful hints.